# why does dynamic allotment showing up critical error while no memory is being freed before the breakpoint achieved in visual studio

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include<cassert>
#include<initializer_list>
#include<iostream>

class IntArray {

int m_length;
int *m_data;

public:
IntArray() : m_length(0), m_data(nullptr) {}
IntArray(int length) : m_length(length) {
    m_data = new int(length);
}
IntArray(const std::initializer_list<int> &list) : IntArray(list.size()) {
    int count = 0;
    for (auto &element : list) {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
        m_data[count] = element;
        ++count;
    }
}
~IntArray() { delete[] m_data; }

int& operator[](int index) {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < m_length);
    return m_data[index];
}

int getLength() { return m_length; }
};

int main() {
    IntArray array{ 4,3,2,1 };
    for (int i = 0; i < array.getLength(); i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Breakpoint achieved at the line system("pause");
Critical error detected in visual studio while the above code works fine in online c++ repl. I just don't get why the above error is showing up on visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour. You allocated memory only for one `int`

```
m_data = new int(length);
```

but you are writing more than one elements, so you are modyfing memory area to which you don't have the access - it is UB.
Change to

```
m_data = new int[length];
```